# How to disable a keybind to allow shift selection with custom cursor keybind

Tags: key-bindings

I have `back-to-indentation` bound to <kbd>M-u</kbd>.

When I hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> with <kbd>M-u</kbd> I'm unable to select the text because <kbd>M-U</kbd> (note the capital 'U') is bound to `upcase-word`


So I disabled that bind by putting: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-U") 'ignore)` in my init file.

But by doing so, holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> with <kbd>M-u</kbd> now does nothing.


So how can I disable a keybind getting in the way of shift selecting with my custom cursor moving keybind?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `M-U` binding by default, so you'll need to try and find the offending binding of `M-U` to `upcase-word`.  You could start with `C-h k M-U` which may tell you "(found in ...)" if you're lucky.

Comment: I just did `(global-set-key (kbd "M-u") 'back-to-indentation)` and it works like you describe it should work with alt+shift+u. It selects text back to indentation.

Comment: I also get the desired behaviour after setting `M-u` to `'back-to-indentation`, as @MaximKim said. Can you show us the code you used to set your keybindings?

Comment: @Tyler It works now. I honestly can't remember how I solved the problem. I should probably delete this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP wants to delete the question (see comments).

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Maxim Kim, it should be as simple as

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-u") 'back-to-indentation)
```

The fact that it's *not* that simple implies there is a collision happening somewhere in your configuration.

Here's how we can tell if it's a collision: start Emacs using `emacs -q`.  That loads Emacs without loading `init.el`.  Run the above code.  If things work as you expect, then there's something in your configuration that's overriding the desired behavior.

Finding where the problem is exactly can be tricky.  I find it helpful to select half of my `init.el` and then do `eval-region`.  If the problem occurs, then we know the conflict is introduced in the first half of the code.  I then select half of the first half of the code and do `eval-region` again.  Eventually, you find the offending line(s) and can begin researching the specific cause.

---

Sometimes when there's a collision, the simplest solution is to find an alternative.  While I don't think that's necessary in your case, here are a few options that provide identical/similar functionality.

It seems like `back-to-indentation` does the same thing as `^` does in `evil-mode`, namely placing point at the first non-white character.

Alternatively, here's a script from my `init.el`, garnered from some kind soul on the Internet:

```
(defun smart-beginning-of-line ()
  "Move point to first non-whitespace character or beginning-of-line.

Move point to the first non-whitespace character on this line.
If point was already at that position, move point to beginning of line."
  (interactive)
  (let ((oldpos (point)))
    (back-to-indentation)
    (and (= oldpos (point))
     (beginning-of-line))))

(global-set-key [home] 'smart-beginning-of-line)
(global-set-key "\C-a" 'smart-beginning-of-line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `(global-unset-key (kbd "M-U"))`? (It is equivalent to `(global-set-key (kbd "M-U") nil)`.)

Comment: Just tried it; it didn't work..